# Google Translate & PHP - Getting alternative translations

Tags: php, google-translate

I have a very simple translation script using Google translate like so:

```
use Google\Cloud\Translate\TranslateClient;
$translate = new TranslateClient([
    'key' => 'xxmyxsuperxsecretxapixkeyxx'
]);

$result = $translate->translate($string, [
    'target' => $lang
]);

$translation = $result['text'];
```

This gives me back a nice array of data like this:

```
array(4) { 
    ["source"]=> string(2) "en" 
    ["input"]=> string(10) "dummy text" 
    ["text"]=> string(11) "dummer Text" 
    ["model"]=> NULL 
}
```

So the first question is what is `$result['model']` in this response?

The second question is, what can I do if I want to get other suggestions like on the actual Google Translate page like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is $result['model'] in this response?

From php client library [docs](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.77.0/translate/translateclient?method=translate):

> The model to use for the translation request.

Regarding your second question: the [translate client](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php/blob/master/Translate/src/TranslateClient.php) sends requests over the REST API and the latter's [docs](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/translate) do not show any support for getting the additional suggestions you see in the translate web UI. One alternative suggestion would be to attempt to scrape the results but, honestly, I have no idea how you could do that using php. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38451783/using-beautifulsoup4-with-google-translate) you can see an answer to an older question regarding doing so with python and BeautifulSoup and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100321/scraping-google-translate) one using node.js, maybe these could prove helpful.